# Blackberry Get ImageListField focus Index

Tags: listview, blackberry, java-me, focus

I have `ImageListField` (custom list). In the menu I have Delete Option I want to delete any element in the list. So I have set the following code. I want to get the row Index of the element which has focus ... I will pass that element ID to **delete** and then process further.

```
public FocusChangeListener listFocus = new FocusChangeListener(){ 
        public void focusChanged(Field field, int eventType) {
            int index = getFieldWithFocusIndex(); 

            Dialog.alert("Index: "+index);
            // But its not giving the specific row index.
        }
    };
list.setFocusListener(listFocus);
```

Also It is being shown 3 times. How to limit it to 1, other than using flags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `getFieldWithFocusIndex()`, which is a method *of the class that contains your ImageListField*, not the ImageListField itself.

If you have a `Manager`, or a `Screen`, that contains the `ImageListField`, then you are asking that object for its field with focus.  That will probably always return the index of your `list` object.  That's the **whole** list, which you don't want.  You want the index of the *row* within that list.  So, you need a different method:

```
  FocusChangeListener listFocus = new FocusChangeListener() { 
     public void focusChanged(Field field, int eventType) {
        //int index = getFieldWithFocusIndex(); 
        int index = list.getSelectedIndex();
        System.out.println("Index: " + index + " event: " + eventType);
     }
  };
  list.setFocusListener(listFocus);
```

Calling `getSelectedIndex()` on your `list` object should work.

As to why you see the method being shown three times, that's probably because there are multiple kinds of focus *events*.  From the [API docs on FocusChangeListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/FocusChangeListener.html):

> static int **FOCUS_CHANGED** 
>             Field prompting the event signals a change in focus.
>   static int **FOCUS_GAINED** 
>             Field prompting the event has gained the focus.
>   static int **FOCUS_LOST** 
>             Field prompting the event has lost the focus.

If you only want to get this notification once, you could add a check for the event type (I don't know if that's what you're calling *flags*, but that's the easiest way to do this):

```
    public void focusChanged(Field field, int eventType) {
        if (eventType == FocusChangeListener.FOCUS_CHANGED) {
           int index = list.getSelectedIndex();
           System.out.println("Index: " + index + " event: " + eventType);
        }
    }
```

Also, maybe this is just in the code you posted for this question, but of course, you will have to store the focused index in a *member variable*.  If you only store it in the local `index` variable, that won't be available to your object when the **Delete** menu item is selected later.